# Android parse String ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, string, parsing, integer

I'm trying to parse a String to obtain 3 Integer but I have a Force Close and the LogCat says : *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions*.

Here is the concerned part of my code :

```
    dateModif = tvDateAffichee.getText().toString();

    String[] separatedDate = dateModif.split(".");

    mDay = Integer.parseInt(separatedDate[0]);
    mMonth = Integer.parseInt(separatedDate[1]);
    mYear = Integer.parseInt(separatedDate[2]);
```

I checked the value of the string with a toast and it contains values like, for example : *13.9.2011*

The mistake comes from this line :

```
    mDay = Integer.parseInt(separatedDate[0]);
```

(If I put it as comment, it gives the same mistake frome the next line)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.split()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex in which case `.` means "any character". You'll want to escape it like this: `\.`. And since you specify the regex as a `String` literal, you'll need to double the backslashes: `dateModif.split("\\.")`.

But it would be better to use real date parsing methods for this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I know that it would be better to use real date parsing but it's for a very particular thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateModif = tvDateAffichee.getText().toString();

String []separatedDate=dateModif.split("[.]");

    mDay = Integer.parseInt(separatedDate[0]);
    mMonth = Integer.parseInt(separatedDate[1]);
    mYear = Integer.parseInt(separatedDate[2]);
```

check this out